# Collision Bounding Boxes Remain after Collisions

Tags: phaser

I am building a multiplayer snake game and I turned on debug mode to see more details of what was happening. After a collision with an apple, the collision bounding box seems to remain and multiple collision bounding boxes are created elsewhere. Is this a problem? If so, is there a way to remove the collision bounding boxes after the collision?

Here is a screenshot of it after only two collisions with the apple (the apple get's re-spawned every time a snake collides with it).
[image: a lot of collision bounding boxes for some reason]

Here is some code that might help add some context to this question (this is part of the code that re-spawns the apple):

```
self.physics.add.overlap(self.ship, self.apple, function () {
        this.socket.emit('appleCollected');
}, null, self);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you are removing the apples you would have to use, something like:

```
self.apple.destroy();
```

**OR**

```
self.apple.disableBody(true, true);
```

in the socket listener function of `appleCollected`.